# Nowaday's Thrashing handling mechanism

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu

I am aiming to research new ways to better handle Thrashing on Linux systems, and I am having a hard time finding what the most recent state-of-the-art is. I desire to gain a good knowledge base on the current handling mechanisms implemented in the Linux Kernel, combined with the most relevant papers I have managed to find - most of them written between 2002-2012. By deeply understanding the topic, I want to experiment with new ideas to improve CPU utilization when Thrashing kicks in.
The most interesting content I have managed to find is:

- TPF: a dynamic system thrashing protection facility .- Song Jiang and Xiaodong Zhang (2002)

Some more recent papers focus more on virtualized environments, but my aim leans towards commercial computers with limited resources. I have tried navigating https://www.kernel.org/ to find information about how Thrashing is currently handled, but I did not succeed.

Do you guys have any suggestions on where to find recent content about the topic?

Pita

Comment: "Thrashing" usually describes the state of a system with virtual memory when it experiences so many page faults it spends more time on paging than progressing with the user applications. The article you linked to also refers to "system thrashing". I never heard of "CPU thrashing". Can you give a definition?

Comment: Hi Hermann, thank you for the suggestion. I am exactly referring to "Thrashing". I have modified the post to be clearer for other members.